# Spinner listener being called when it should not

Tags: android, listener

The Listener is getting called here when I set the selection. The problem here is, I'm setting the selection BEFORE the Listener.

How can I avoid this behavior?

```
Spinner spCategories = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerCategories);
ArrayAdapter<String> aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.spinner_item, this.categoryList);
spCategories.setAdapter(aa);
spCategories.setSelection(selectedA);
spCategories.setOnItemSelectedListener(oiclSpCategories);
```

Comment: You mean to say Spinner's onItemSelected method is getting called when u set selection?

Comment: I mean that oiclSpCategories onItemSelected method gets called when I run that code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to register `OnItemSelectedListener` with `post` method:

```
spCategories.post(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        spCategories.setOnItemSelectedListener(oiclSpCategories);
    } 
});
```

Comment: Wow, it works! Why isn't this the standard behaviour? It's kind of strange.